# Default getdate() value error SQL AZURE

Tags: database, sql, datetime, azure

I received this error when I try `Save Changed` in my table on SQL AZURE

> An error was encountered while applying the changes. An exception
>   occurred while executing the Transact-SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo]. [TbUser] 
  ALTER COLUMN [DtUpdated] DATETIME NOT NULL
```

> Cannot insert the value `NULL`
>   into column `'DtUpdated', table 'AudiData.dbo. TbUser';`
>   column does not allow nulls. `UPDATE` fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I put the default value `getdate()` in designer page `management portal - sql database`.

How put the `getdate()` with default value in a `null` column on sql azure?

Answer (score 0):

The table probably has `null` values in that column.  Remove or update them before you apply a `not null` constraint.